# Filter rows that contain ":" in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr, filter, tidyverse

Given the dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(x = c("A:B","B:C","D","E","F"),
                y = c("1","2","3","4","5"))
```

How do I keep just the rows that contain ":" in column x? Normally, I would just use `dplyr::filter()` to delete the rows containing the string but the following code doesn't seem to work:

```
df %>% filter(x %in% ":")
```

It seems like ":" may be breaking it because it deletes all rows, but I can't seem to figure out how else to indicate ":" in R.

*Edit*: If there are other symbols that also trigger this issue then a general solution would also be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>% filter(grepl(":", x))
```

Comment: you can also use `stringr` to improve code readability: `df %>% filter(str_detect(x,":"))`

Answer (score 0):

In base R:
We could add the logic to the row parameter in the brackets:

```
df[grepl(':',df$x),]
```

```
  x y
1 A:B 1
2 B:C 2
```